# Efficiency with a Structure

Tags: c, performance, struct, linked-list

I have the following structure

```
struct scoreentry_node {
    struct scoreentry_node *next;
    int score;
    int max;
    char name[1];    
}
;
typedef struct scoreentry_node *score_entry;
```

And i have the function `add` that builds my structure:

```
int max(int a, int b) {    
   if (a > b) return a;
   return b;
}

score_entry add(int in, char* n, score_entry en) {      
   score_entry r = malloc(sizeof(struct scoreentry_node) + strlen(n))
   if (en == NULL){ r->max = in; }
   else {  r->max = max(in, en->max); }
   r->score = in;
   strcpy(r->name, n);
   r->next = en;  
   return r;   
}
```

I have the following function, that scans through my structure searching for a name and produces the highest score of that name:

```
int maxiscore(score_entry a, char* name)
{    
 int highestscore = -1000000000;    
   for (a; a != NULL; a = a->next)
    {
      if (strcmp(a->name, name) == 0 && a->score > highestscore)
        {
          highestscore = a->score;                
       }
     }
 return highestscore;
}
```

I was wondering if i can make my `maxiscore` function run in O(1) [doesn't have to scan through my structure]? I was thinking about adding another field to my struct but i have to consider that it need's to vary depending on a specific inputted name. Any Suggestions/ Hints?

Comment: What is a `char name[1];` ? If you want a single char, why not have just `char name;` ? If you want it to be null-terminated string, then **only** the null terminator will fit into a single-char array.

Comment: The only way to make it O(1) is to keep the list constantly sorted, which would be a much bigger waste than have max score be O(n).

Comment: The only ways to make it O(1) is to implement the list as a `priorityQueue` (ie sorted) or to implement the list as a `HashTable`. With your current setup the `HashTable` option requires basically redoing the entire code. You could implement a `priorityQueue`.

Comment: @Imp It's a variable array member. Every byte additionally malloced "goes into" the length of that array, in this case he mallocs strlen(n) additional bytes, so his array is 1 + strlen(n) long, enough to hold a string of length n.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, twain249: terribly wrong :)

Comment: @Imp, @Anthales: the `[1]` trick works in all C systems I have ever seen, but is not Officially Blessed; C99 offers the "flexible array member" approach instead, where you omit the size entirely.  Of course then you need `strlen(n) + 1` to account for the `'\0'`.

Comment: @twain249 a priority queue alone is not O(1) because you search not only for the score but for the name too. A hash table with the name as index and a priority queue for _each_ name would do. Another next pointer in `scoreentry_node` would be nice to keep the scores of all players in order too...

Answer (score 1):

As some commenters noted this is basically an algorithm / data-organization question.

You can spend time creating "organized" data structures, such as a per-user score table, hashes, balanced trees, and so on; or you can spend time searching "disorganized" data structures.  There are even hybrid approaches: create them "disorganized" and then organize them on the fly, as needed (e.g., splay trees).

If you already have information about what you will "do the most", you can optimize now.  Otherwise, if you want to be able to optimize later, decide what sort of functionality you require, and provide specific functions to "do each thing" (add a name with a set of scores? add one name with one score? find all scores for a particular name? find the N highest scores? find the N highest scores for a particular name? any/all of the preceding? etc).  Once it's all working, use profiling to find out where the time goes, and then choose how to organize the data accessed via those function(s).

As it is, I think your question starts a little "too low level", i.e., "I already have this particular set of nails, so which hammer should I use" when maybe screws or glue would be better. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap a set of the structures in a `scorelist` class containing `score_entry` pointer to the first element and biggest score (and a pointer to related element) among contained entries. You can update the biggets score on `add()` and rewrite the pointer. You will be able to access an element with biggest score in O(1).

Comment: Why am i dealing with smallest score's thou ? and how exactly would i "add a pointer to related element" ?

Comment: You seemply **always** keep a pointer to the element with the biggest score. You can access this element via pointer inside add() and rewrite the pointer if added element has bigger score.

Comment: Add a field say `struct scoreentry_node *highscore;` that will point to a struct with a name and the highest score ? ... But what if i dont want that specific names score ?

Comment: I don't understand you. Once you maintain `highscore` pointer, you'll be able to access entry with the highest score, obtain it's name, exact score and whatsoever. That's exactly what you've been asking for.

Comment: Aaaah, I get it. Well, the best thing for you is hash-table.

Comment: Yeaa i don't want to find the name with the highscore, i want to find a specific person's `highscore` ... Thanks for the help thou ! :)